# How to take differentiate this value in TSQL?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

We have a simplified table like this:

```
TYPE; VALUE
AA; 10
BB; 7
CC; 12
```

I want to do calculation based on TYPE AA & BB so 10 - 7 = 3

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select A.TYPE - B.TYPE
  from table A, table B
 where A.TYPE = 'AA'
   and B.TYPE = 'BB'

Comment: Except that implied join syntax is a very poor programming technique and you should use explicit joins. Honestly this stuff was replaced in 1992, why are you still using it?

Comment: You are right actually but I'm editing procedures more than 5000 lines in sybase and this way is traditional in my job :)